# Database solve repeating primary key

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a database such that there are many facilities that are charged under a certain bill ID, but if more than one facility is charged under the same Bill ID, then repeating primary key bill ID would be existing in the Bill table and that make a problem in MySQL, how could I solve this problem?

[image: SQL Table diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have duplicate primary keys.

What you probably want is for your Facility table to contain the Bill ID

BILL
BillId

FACILITY
FacilityID
BillID
Fac_name
Fac_Price

then you can Join the two tables with

`Select * from BILL join FACILITY on (BILL.BillID=Facility.FacilityID) where BillId=123`

---Edit

BILL
BillId
123
345
678

FACILITY
FacilityID, BillId
1         , 123
2         , 123
3         , 123
4         , 345
5         , 345
6         , 678
7         , 678
8         , 678

See the Teacher -< Classes diagram on this page

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html

Comment: but if i make the facility_Id the Primary key of Table facility, and there are more than one bill charging the same facility, wouldn't the facility_id (primary key of facility table) repeats and creating same problem?

Comment: Each facility ID will be different, but the BillID in the Facility table will be the same for each related entry